# trying to translate the specific text of multiple xml files and then modify each files

Tags: python, xml, exception, file-handling

I am trying to translate the specific element of multiple xml files and then the translated text write back to each files.
Here is the xml file : I need to translate the body and headline text in English and overwrite it on each files according to their translated text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<COUNTER_document totalnoofwords="364" totalnoofsentences="13" noofwordswithSWR="248" newspaper="express" newsdate="02.12.14" filename="0002p.xml" domain="sports" classification="ND">

<headline>تیج نے کرکٹ تاریخ میں سنہری حروف سے نام درج کرالیا ون ڈے ڈیبیو پر ہیٹرک کرنیوالے دنیا کے پہلے پلےئر،سیریز میں بنکلہ دیش کا کلین سوائپ</headline>

<body>ڈھاکہ (سپورٹس ڈیسک/اے ایف پی ) تیج الاسلام نے کر کٹ تاریخ میں سنہری حروف سے نام درج کرا لیا، بنگلہ دیشی اسپنر ون ڈے ڈیبیو پر ہیٹرک کرنے والے دنیا کے پہلے کھلاڑی بن گئے،بنگلہ دیش نے پانچویں مقابلے میں 5 وکٹ کی فتح سے کلین سوائپ مکمل کر لیا، میزبان سائیڈ نے 129 رنز کا ہدف پانچ پلیئرز کے نقصان پر حاصل کیا،محمود اللہ 51 رنز پر ناٹ آؤٹ رہے۔تفصیلات کے مطابق بنگلہ دیشی تیج الاسلام نے اولین ون ڈے میں ہیٹرک کا کارنامہ سرانجام دینے والےدنیا کے پہلے کرکٹر کا اعزاز حاصل کر لیا، </body>

</COUNTER_document>
```

This is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from googletrans import Translator
import glob

path="D:\\Counter\\*.*"

#Access All the files from given folder
file_list = glob.glob(path)
print(file_list)

#Load each file at a time.
for file in glob.glob(path):
   
#Translate object
 translator = Translator()
 mytree = ET.parse(file)
 myroot = mytree.getroot()
 
for urdu in myroot.iter('body'):
    content= urdu.text

 result = translator.translate(content, dest='en')
 
 urdu.text = result
 mytree.write(file)
```

the text was translated successfully but here i want to write the translated text back to each file but i don't know ho to do this. your help will be highly appreciated. THanks

Comment: Indent `result = ...` and `urdu.text = ...` to be a part of the loop `for urdu in ...`. You also need to be more specific about the problem. What is wrong?

Comment: The main issue is that the translated text is not write on each files. When i try to write it.The file become empty(no text).I used mytree.write(file) but error came and said "cannot serialize <googletrans.models.translated object at 0x0000029151a31ba0> (type translated)

Comment: Can you convert `result` to text before writing to the file? =>`urdu.text = str(result)`

Comment: Thanks a lot fam-woodpecker. It is working now.